# On launch Alert

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Here the code which i have used in sencha based application,In that i want to add a alert prompting enter your password! when the **indexpnl** launch.Here the code

```
var mainContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    id: 'mainContainer',
    layout: 'card',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    showAnimation: {
                    type: 'slideIn',
                    direction: 'right'
                   },
    items: [indexpnl,loginpnl,registerpnl,homepnl,viewitemspnl,forgpanel,myfriendpro,notifypanel,mapapnel,friendviewitemspnl]
    });
    Ext.Viewport.add({
        xtype: 'panel',
        items: [mainContainer]
    });
```

Alert

```
 function alertprompt()
 {
 var retVal = prompt("Enter your password? ", "Password");
 }
```

When application starts indexpnl shows first.I want to show the above alert with that.Where should i want to call the method alertprompt() to show on launch?PLease help to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are calling `Ext.onReady();` to invoke your function which shows `indexpnl`.

Lets assume this function is `start()`.

```
function start() {
    //do your panel rendering to where ever
    alertprompt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this listener just add the below code

listeners:{

```
         afterrender:function(t,eOpts){

            alert("Enter your password");

        }

      }
```

Comment: Where should i want to add this listener...in mainContainer or in Ext.Viewport.add

Answer (score 0):

If you are using launch function to add xtype into your Viewport. You can use "Ext.Msg.prompt(...)" there. After password get's successful you can add pannel into the viewport. Note : I am assuming that your going to display your main container after password validation.
Eg :`

```
    launch:function(){
     Ext.Msg.prompt('Authentication Process!','Please enter your password:', function(button,text){
       if(button=='ok'){
         //Do your password validation here. Then add your panel into the Viewport
       }
       else
       {
         Ext.Msg.alert('Reload the application and give your password');
       }
     });
   },
```

`

Comment: Yes. after password validation i want to show main container.Here where should i want to show the alert And how

Comment: I have added sample code how to add prompt msg for your validation. And this function should be defined in app.js file.